# PanResponder does not block ScrollView on iOS

Tags: react-native

I want a view component to block all parent ScrollViews when moving the finger in this area.

The PanResponder does not block the ScrollView. But only on iOS. Android works as it should. I thought this is exactly what the PanResponder with the functions "shouldSet*" is for? Did I miss something?

Here is an example: https://snack.expo.dev/fKP048VbJ

React Native Version: 0.65.1